# would it be the same to detach() first instead sync() in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Would detach() then attach() again have the same effect as sync?

I mean could I use this

```
$user->settings()->detach(44);
$user->settings()->attach(44, ['extra'=>'data]);
```

instead this

```
$user->settings()->attach([44 => ['extra'=>'data]]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sync, you actually "sync" the data you provide with the DB.

Let's say you want to sync posts to a user :

```
User::find($someUser)->posts()->sync([5, 7]);
```

OR

```
User::find($someUser)->posts()->attach(5);
User::find($someUser)->posts()->attach(7);
```

sync() will keep in DB the IDs you pass to it, where attach() add to the existing data.